# xml elements from sql

Tags: xml, t-sql

First time writing TSQL to output XML.

Below is the format of XML I'm attempting to output. [image]

I've started putting together the code below -

```
SELECT              1 as 'PropRecordType'
                    ,a.AssetReference as 'PropCliReference'



FROM  Asset a
LEFT JOIN AssetType at on at.AssetTypeId = a.AssetTypeID



WHERE at.Letable = 1

FOR XML PATH('Property'), 
ROOT ('UESDPropertyDetails');
```

So I'm comfortable getting the list of elements added within the Property section.
It's how I get the RiskAssessementList part of the data in the Property Section?

Comment: Please post structure and sample data for both tables (`Asset` and `AssetType`)

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing here was your job actually (creating a test scenario). Try it out:

```sql
DECLARE @propTable TABLE(ID INT, eMail VARCHAR(100),ward VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @propTable VALUES(1,'Some@email.com','blah');

DECLARE @AssessmentTable TABLE(ID INT, PropID INT /*fk*/, Code VARCHAR(100),Descr VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @AssessmentTable VALUES(1,1,'GPO','')
                                  ,(2,1,'ASB','001');
```

--the query

```sql
SELECT pt.eMail AS PropEMail
      ,pt.ward AS PropWard
      ,(
        SELECT at.Code AS AssessmentCode
              ,at.Descr AS AssessmentDesc
        FROM @AssessmentTable at
        WHERE at.PropID=pt.ID
        FOR XML PATH('RiskAssessment'),ROOT('RiskAssessmentList'),TYPE
       )
FROM @propTable pt
FOR XML PATH('Property'),ROOT('UESDPropertyDetail');
```

The result

```
<UESDPropertyDetail>
  <Property>
    <PropEMail>Some@email.com</PropEMail>
    <PropWard>blah</PropWard>
    <RiskAssessmentList>
      <RiskAssessment>
        <AssessmentCode>GPO</AssessmentCode>
        <AssessmentDesc />
      </RiskAssessment>
      <RiskAssessment>
        <AssessmentCode>ASB</AssessmentCode>
        <AssessmentDesc>001</AssessmentDesc>
      </RiskAssessment>
    </RiskAssessmentList>
  </Property>
</UESDPropertyDetail>
```